# вложенные циклы (вызов прямой и обратной последовательности)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, люди. подскажите новичку по вложенным циклам. нужно сделать последовательность от 1 до 9 с вставкой между ними последовательности от 9  до 1.
пытаюсь сделать таким образом, но что-то не получается.

```
 int i, j;
 for (i=1, j=9; i<=9, j=>1; i++, j--){
       System.out.printf(%d i);
       System.out.printf(%d j);
    }
```

были еще варианты: for с меткой типа loop, break-continue, switch-case. их нужно зациклить и из внутреннего вызвать внешний, и наоборот. но наиболее простой способ-как я предлагаю, наверное.. как зациклить switch-case?
должно получиться: 192837465564738291 без массива) и просто циклами.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял вы сюда приходите с учебными задачами, лучше решайте их сами (как угодно криво) и приходите с проблемами в решении. Четко поставьте вопрос, что хотите получить, что получаете и что на ваш взгляд не работает.

Сейчас вы списываете, это не пойдет вам на пользу.

Для этой задачи опишу алгоритм, а закодируете вы его сами:

```
1. Первый цикл от 1 до 10 (10 не включается)
1.1 Вывести счетчик цикла
1.2 вывести 10 минус счетчик цикла
```

все. число 10 можно вынести в отдельную переменную, по желанию

---

> for с меткой типа loop, break-continue

старайтесь их использовать только в краних случаях, они не очень вписываются в код (наследие си'шного goto)

Comment: Здравствуйте. алгоритм я понимаю. сложность в том, что нужно увязать 2 цикла. после одной итерации внутреннего-перейти во внешний, после итерации внешнего перейти во внутренний. я кучу вариантов перепробовал, перед тем как полез сюда, но безуспешно. а найденных вариант, который я предложил удивил свой простотой и красотой. но увы, как я ни подбирал, условия не сработал. поэтому и хотел спросить. мне показывали мимолетом, что решается это через break-continue. но тольком не понял и не запомнил.. поэтому, вы правы, буду читать внимательнее область действия переменной. вариант б.панченко-шикарно)

Comment: @Виктор , вложенный цикл обязательное условие? Это важно, т.к. в этой задаче он лишний, по логике. Использовать конечно можно, но это как экскаватором копать клумбы...

Answer (score 0):

можно пройтись от 0, избавимся от +1, и правильней формализуйте ворос

```
for (int i=1; i<=9; i++){
    System.out.printf(%d i);
    System.out.printf(%d (9-i+1));
}
```

Comment: посмотрите на то, что нужно автору и посмотрите на свой вывод =)

Comment: @Виктор "Здравствуйте, люди. подскажите новичку по вложенным циклам. нужно сделать последовательность от 1 до 9 с вставкой между ними последовательности от 9 до 1"- тут или код ег онеправильный или задаваемый ворос. У него в коде не вложеныый цикл, а спареный.

Comment: @Виктор а на счет сишного я имел ввиду что переменные за циклом определены

Comment: Первый раз слышу определение "спаренный", но "должно получиться: 192837465564738291 без массива"

Comment: @Виктор тогда еще проще

Comment: @Виктор "Первый раз слышу определение "спаренный"" - по другому назвать сложно, цикл с 2-й итерация(но там деинкрементация)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, разберитесь с синтаксисом циклов. Во-вторых, с областью видимости переменных. В-третьих, раз вы говорите о вложенных циклах, то циклов должно быть как минимум 2, тогда один будет расположен в пределах другого. А у вас всего один цикл...

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++){
for (int k=9; k>0; i--){
...
}
}
```

И подсказка - вложенные циклы выглядят примерно так